# Why my server is not receiving post req? Could not get response

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

i am building a backed end for my app, but when i am trying to post a post req from postman to my server for testing that is i am going right, but unfortunately my server don't even get any req from postman, inside my postman software is showing Sending request... for 2-3 mins than it's showing me Could not get response,

Does anyone know How can i fix it? i tried to read my code 3-4 times but i can't find my mistake, i also checked spelling, file locations, and even restarted my server but can't find my mistake yet, can anyone tell me where i am wrong?

server.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const port = 3000
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
require('./db');
require('./Models/user');
const Authroutes = require('./routes/Auth');


app.use(bodyParser.json);
app.use(Authroutes);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('sever is running at 3000!');
})
```

Auth.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = mongoose.model('User');
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
require('dotenv').config();
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");


router.post('/verify', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
})

module.exports = router;
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not configured the bodyParser middleware appropriately.

Change this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json)
```

to this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

You need the parens after `bodyParser.json()` to generate the proper middleware function.  Passing `bodyParser.json` by itself wasn't generating an error, but it also wasn't working properly either.

---

In fact, you can simplify further by removing the body-parser module entirely because that is built into Express so, you can remove this:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
```

And, change this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json)
```

to this:

```
app.use(express.json());
```

Comment: unfortunately its not working

Comment: @HelloWorld - Well, this change is required.  There must be something else wrong too.  Are you 100% sure the incoming request has `content-type: application/json`?  And, when you say "it's not working", what exactly happens?  Can you show us the exact POSTMAN request?

Comment: yep i added content-type: application/json and when i am consoling res.body than its showing undefined, you can check my edited question

Comment: What is the body of the request that you're sending from POSTMAN?  Your screenshot doesn't show that.

Comment: {
    "email": "hello00@gmail.com"
}

Comment: Hey i was i fix it

Comment: @HelloWorld - What fixed it?

Comment: actually i was doing console wrong everything was fine i think i forget to put parens, strange but everything happens subconsciously

Comment: OK, so the parens in this answer was the problem?